# Download YouTube via command line

Tags: youtube

In Firefox I use "DownloadHelper", is there a Mac OS X || Ubuntu command line tool that downloads YouTube videos for offline viewing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/). It's a CLI python script so it shall work on any platform that has python installed.

Comment: [Here](http://bitbucket.org/rg3/youtube-dl/wiki/Home) is a link to the webpage.

Comment: If you use homebrew, try `brew install youtube-dl`

Comment: `pip3 install --user --upgrade youtube_dl`