# How to download a Youtube video from command line?

Tags: command-line, download, youtube, video-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download YouTube via command line](https://superuser.com/questions/149123/download-youtube-via-command-line)

How to download a Youtube video from command line?  Mac OS X and/or Ubuntu Linux. Optionally, i'd like to save it in .avi or .mkv format.

Comment: For ubuntu check out: [sudo apt-get install youtube-dl](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177659/how-can-i-download-the-videos-from-youtube)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/) works on OS X, Linux and Windows, and can download videos in any format YouTube provides. You can use other tools like mencoder to change the codec or container format afterwards.